# don't know whats causing this error in my interpreter ( python )

Tags: python, interpreter

making a language interpreter in python but ran through this error, it only shows 2 strings then shows the error. why is that?
it worked fine before printing all NUMs and EXPRs, the problem seems to be mostly in the parse function.

```
from sys import *

tokens = []

def open_file(filename):
    data = open(filename, 'r').read()
    data += "<EOF>"
    return data

def lex(filecontents):
    tok = ""
    state = 0
    string = ""
    expr = ""
    n = ""
    isexpr = 0
    for char in filecontents:
        tok += char
        if tok == " ":
            if state == 0:
                tok = ""
            else:
                tok = " "
        elif tok == "\n" or tok =="<EOF>":
            if expr != "" and isexpr == 1:
                tokens.append("EXPR:" + expr)
                expr = ""
            elif expr != "" and isexpr == 0:
                tokens.append("NUM:" + expr)
                expr = ""
            tok = ""
        elif tok == "PRINT" or tok == "print":
            tokens.append("PRINT")
            tok = ""
        elif tok == "0" or tok == "1" or tok == "2" or tok == "3" or tok == "4" or tok == "5" or tok == "6" or tok == "7" or tok == "8" or tok == "9":
            expr += tok
            tok = ""
        elif tok == "+":
            isexpr = 1
            expr += tok
            tok = ""
        elif tok == "\"":
            if state == 0:
                state = 1
            elif state == 1:
                tokens.append("STRING:" + string + "\"")
                string = ""
                state = 0
                tok = ""
        elif state == 1:
            string += tok
            tok = ""
    #print(tokens)
    return tokens

def parse(toks):
    i = 0
    while(i < len(toks)):
        if toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:6] == "PRINT STRING" or toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:3] == "PRINT NUM" or toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:4] == "PRINT EXPR":
            if toks[i+1][0:6] == "STRING":
                print(toks[i+1][7:])
            elif toks[i+1][0:3] == "NUM":
                print(toks[i+1][4:])
            elif toks[i+1][0:4] == "EXPR":
                print(toks[i+1][5:])
            i+= 2

def run():
    data = open_file(argv[1])
    toks = lex(data)
    parse(toks)

run()
```

```
PRINT "HELLO WORLD"
print "string"
566755664645454
5 + 6
print 55
print 5 + 8
```

```
PS C:\Users\essam\Desktop\spl> python basic.py test.lang
"HELLO WORLD"
"string"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\essam\Desktop\spl\basic.py", line 73, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\essam\Desktop\spl\basic.py", line 71, in run
    parse(toks)
  File "C:\Users\essam\Desktop\spl\basic.py", line 58, in parse
    while(i < len(toks)):
              ^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt
PS C:\Users\essam\Desktop\spl>
```

I tried changing the parse function but my attempts ended up printing 566755664645454 but not 5 + 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def parse(toks):
    i = 0
    while(i < len(toks)):
        if toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:6] == "PRINT STRING" or toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:3] == "PRINT NUM" or toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:4] == "PRINT EXPR":
            ...
            i+= 2
```

If that first `if` condition is not true, the `while` loop will run forever, testing the same condition over and over, because `i` does not change.

I think maybe you wanted the `i += 2` to be at the same indentation level as the `if`, not nested inside of it.

Comment: ohhhhh, I don't know how I didn't notice that. thanks john